# (Num a) is not inferred with functions as applicative

Tags: haskell

I have this simple example of functions as applicative:

```
$> :t (+) <$> Just (+5) <*> Just(+3)
(+) <$> Just (+5) <*> Just(+3)
  :: (Num (a -> a), Num a) => Maybe (a -> a)
```

so the expected returned value should be `Maybe (a -> a)`, basically a function wrapped in `Maybe` context. I pass it to a Monad to be able to use it, in this:

```
$> (+) <$> Just (+5) <*> Just(+3) >>= (\x -> Just (x $ 7))

<interactive>:116:1: error:
    • Non type-variable argument in the constraint: Num (b -> b)
      (Use FlexibleContexts to permit this)
    • When checking the inferred type
        it :: forall b. (Num (b -> b), Num b) => Maybe b
```

but as you can see, there is an error that I think is related to the fact that is not possible to infer the type for the type variable a, that in this case is `Num a`.

How can I make it work?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In `(+) <$> Just (+5) <*> Just(+3)`, `(<$>)` and `(<*>)` only involve the `Maybe` context, and not the function one. A sign that it doesn't express what you intended is the inferred type:

```
(+) <$> Just (+5) <*> Just(+3) :: (Num (a -> a), Num a) => Maybe (a -> a)
```

Note the `Num (a -> a)` constraint. It shows up because you are trying to apply `(+)` directly to the `(+5)` function within `Just (+5)`, which is not what you wanted.

What you need to do is to handle both layers of applicative context. A convenient way to do so is through [the `Compose` newtype](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Data-Functor-Compose.html):

```
GHCi> import Data.Functor.Compose
GHCi> :t getCompose ((+) <$> Compose (Just (+5)) <*> Compose (Just (+3)))
getCompose ((+) <$> Compose (Just (+5)) <*> Compose (Just (+3)))
  :: Num a => Maybe (a -> a)
```

The relevant instances for `Compose` make sure `fmap` and `(<*>)` handle both layers of context appropriately. Quoting the relevant bits of the source code in *base*:

```
newtype Compose f g a = Compose { getCompose :: f (g a) }

instance (Functor f, Functor g) => Functor (Compose f g) where
    fmap f (Compose x) = Compose (fmap (fmap f) x)

instance (Applicative f, Applicative g) => Applicative (Compose f g) where
    pure x = Compose (pure (pure x))
    Compose f <*> Compose x = Compose ((<*>) <$> f <*> x)
```